# [java]Add the jar fail,I can't ues the class

Tags: java

I have added the jar to Build path and the Reference Libraries also have the jar.IDE is the eclipse2019.9. Can you see my image?I can't sure whether it was posted

```
package com.itranswarp.learnjava;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
public class Main {
    static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Start process...");
        try {
            "".getBytes("invalidCharsetName");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        log.info("Process end.");
    }
}
```

[screenshot:This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umtHW.png)

Comment: Please share the exception stack trace and Project structure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description and/or screenshots of how you have added the JAR file to the build path, how you have added reference libraries and how you have compile it. Give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please add build path.. refer image

Comment: Sorry ,I am a new account,I can't post the image before I answer ten questions....
I had add build path,but it doesn't work